# Shouldn't $\int\int f(r,p,t)d^3r d^3p$ be less than $1$ for $N>1$?

Tags: integration

I am reading [this article on Boltzmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation).

It says the following: Consider a system of $N$ particles. Let $f(r,p,t)$ be the probability of all $N$ particles being at position $r$ and having momentum $p$. Then $N=\int\int f(r,p,t)d^3r d^3p$.

Shouldn't $\int\int f(r,p,t)d^3r d^3p$ be less than $1$ for $N>1$? What is the probability of all $N$ particles having the same position and momentum at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It is the probability of a particle being at position $r$ and momentum $p$.  Each particle is somewhere and at some momentum.  The "all" in the article is all the particles at this position and momentum, not all the particles in the system, so if there are two particles at this position and momentum, the integral around there of $f$ is $2$.

Comment: Your $f=2$ claim is wrong; that's not how densities work.

Comment: @J.G.  This one integrates to the total number of particles, not to $1$.  It is also only integrated over three dimensions each in space and momentum, not $3N$ each.

Comment: You've missed my point. My point is that unitarity tells you $f$'s integral, not $f$, which for given $r,\,p$ can take any value $\ge0$.

Comment: @J.G.:  you are right I missed the point.  I have updated